# C programme error "left operand of assignment"

Tags: c

Can anyone explain me why this line of code is wrong?

```
int n = 0, y = 1;
y == 1 ? n = 0 : n = 1;
```

The error is `"Lvalue required as left operand of assignment "` for `"n=1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
(y == 1 ? n = 0 : n) = 1;
```

is interpreted as because `n` binds with `?:` operator due to its higher precedence.
`=` needs l-value as its left operand while `?:` returns an r-value.
Try this instead

```
y == 1 ? n = 0 : (n = 1);
```

or

```
n = y == 1 ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand. But whether or not this is a question for a begginer or intermediate? the knowledge about compiler seems to be far away from a begginer.

Comment: The compiler has no choice in this matter. The language says that that's how the text is to be interpreted...

Comment: @webrocker; I faced this problem too when I started learning C. :P

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
n = y==1 ? 0 :1
```

According to the C standard, the behaviour is undefined if an attempt is made to use the result of the conditional operator as an Lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for assigning for example:

```
int n = 0, y = 1;
n = y == 1 ? 0 : 1;
```